# Do I need VS 2012 Express for Windows 8 Apps if I have VS 2012 Professional?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

Every page I seem to point to while trying to learn how to develop Win8 apps (such as [this MS Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211386#part_1_setup)) points me to a download package that includes "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8."

However, I already have VS 2012 Pro.

Do I still need to obtain VS 2012 Express for Windows 8 for some reason, or is there an alternate path I can take to continue to use my existing VS 2012 in order to build Windows 8 apps?

Comment: No.  Pick a project template from the "Windows Store" node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition for Windows 8 can create and edit Windows Store projects. Those same projects can be opened and edited in Visual Studio 2012 Pro and Ultimate. However, Visual Studio 2012 Pro and Ultimate can create other types of projects (like Windows Phone, WCP, WPF) that cannot be opened by VS 2012 Express Edition because Express for Windows 8 Apps is intentionally limited to only build Windows 8 apps.

The answer to your question is no, you do not need Express if you have Pro. Pro is the superset of the Express editions. Other Express editions include Windows Phone, Web, and Windows Apps. They are the free edition of Visual Studio, and for that reason alone they are limited in features.

Answer (score 2):

Express is the cut-down edition of VS and as such it is less capable than the Pro edition. So, you should stick to VS 2012 Pro which is more than capable of developing Windows 8 apps.

Comment: Hi David, I share that opinion, but it didn't answer my question, which I guess I should have formed better -- how do I create a Windows 8 app without downloading the VS Express package. Hans Passant answered this in his comment. Thank you though!

Comment: David, a fair point -- the downvote was not properly thought out. Apologies; I'll be seeking to change it. If you could edit your answer, it would enable me to change the vote.